# Text inside child section pushes parent section down

Tags: html, css

So I have this HTML and CSS here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, World!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <section id="sidebar">
                <section class="widget">
                This is a Widget. This type of widget is not collapsible.
                </section>
            </section><!-- I hate "display: inline-block;" whitespace
         --><main>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body, #wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #5C1B88;

    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
}

    #sidebar > .widget
    {
        width: 260px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 20px;
        background-color: rgb(210, 211, 228);
    }

main {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #C2A1E7;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

In both Firefox and Chrome, the `section#sidebar` is pushed down whenever I have text inside the child, `section.widget`. What' s causing this?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NeonGuilmon/k6qrbm04/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default, inline elements have a [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) value of `baseline`. This applies only once it has any content, though. The solution is simple, define `vertical-align: top;` for `#sidebar`.